# T-SQL Dynamic Pivot not working correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, azure-sql-database

I have `keys` and `values` kind of data structure in one of our dimension tables
both keys and values columns are `nvarchar(500)`
I am doing a data quality check to ensure figures returned by the pivot query matches with the actual number of values for keys within the dim table which is fine for most of the keys. However
for some keys the count returned by the pivot query is less than the actual number of values in the key value data structure
for example one of the key is Education and values are

```
Education school
Education sixthform
Education Titulo de Bachiller
Education SQA Highers
...
...
```

when I run the pivot query `where Education is not null` then rows returned are 23
when I run the query on dim table where key = Education then rows returned are 128

I am using following pivot query

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                DROP TABLE #TempTable
            END
        
        DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
        
        SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                                    ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Key])
                           FROM     dbo.DimTable c
            FOR           XML PATH(''),
                              TYPE
                                    ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
        
        SET @query = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),' (SELECT OrganisationGuid, Total, ') + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@cols)
            + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),'
              into #TempTable
             from 
                    (
                         SELECT
                          
                          OrganisationGuid,
                          Total,
                          [Key],
               [Value]
               
              FROM dbo.DimTable
                   ) x
                    pivot
                    (
                         max([Value])
                        for [Key] in (') + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@cols) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),')
                    ) p ) 
                    
                    
                    select * from  #TempTable t where t.[Education] is not null order by t.[Education]
       
                    ')
        
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

there is a column uniqueID which is unique for every row in dim table and if I include that column in the pivot query then result matches with the count in actual dim table.

I need to know why pivot query returns less records for some keys and not for all keys and how including uniqueID column makes different to the total when included in the pivot query

this is my simple query to identify number of rows for any specific key

```
        SELECT * FROM dbo.DimTable
WHERE [Key] = 'Education' order by [value]
```

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the statement first. Then you can debug that SQL first, and solve the problem before propagating the solution to your SQL that generates the dynamic statement. Often you'll find that the problems are quite simple, such as a typographical error that is difficult to stop in the literal strings, a missing whitespace/linebreak, or leading/trailing delimiters. Taking the time to get the non-dynamic statement working first is really important, as if that doesn't work the dynamic one will have no chance of working correctly.

Comment: RE "I need to know why pivot query returns less records for some keys": if you observe carefully you will note that `PIVOT` does aggregation i.e. `max([Value]) for [Key]` (note the **max()** function). If you do not include a "Unique Group ID" column in the result set then pivot applies aggregation to all records as one group. It works in similar way to a regular `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: thanks @Alex that's exactly the problem, I have been reading on how pivot works and you are absolutely right without uniqueID it won't be accurate

Comment: thanks @Larnu  I printed entire sql and no issues with the keys, its to do with grouping as mentioned Alex in his comments

Answer (score 0):

The query on **DimTable** returns more records because you are querying to get the record count of value '**Education**' from the Column `[Key]`

**Example**: Below is the DimTable

[image]

- When you are getting the records where the `Key` column equals to '**Education**' then it returns all records which satisfy where clause irrespective of Value column data.

  ```
    select * from DimTable where [Key] = 'Education' order by [Key]
  ```

[image]

2. In your Pivot query you are converting the value '**Education**' to column `[Education]` by Value, so the column Education contains the data of column Value, and when you check the pivot query where Education is NOT NULL, it returns records where Value of DimTable is not null.

Pivot query result where education is not null:

[image]

So, the **Pivot** query might contain lesser records compared to when you query DimTable on Education if there are any NULL values in column Value.

Comment: I would up vote your answer for the effort of making screenshots but I am struggling to make sense of the text explanation.